# Remove line below header on title page

Tags: header-footer, context, titles

How to remove the line below header on title page using this minimal example:

```
\setuppapersize[A4]

\setuplayout
    [width=fit, height=fit,
     topspace=2cm, header=\lineheight, headerdistance=\lineheight,
     footer=0cm]

\setupbackgrounds[header][text][bottomframe=on]  % line below header
\setupheadertexts[chapter][pagenumber]
\setuppagenumbering[location=]  % clear page number

\definemakeup[titlepage]

\starttext

\startfrontmatter
    \starttitlepagemakeup
        {\raggedcenter
            {\bfb XXXXXXX \\ XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX\par}
            \blank[1cm]
            {\bfd XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX\par}
            \blank[1cm]
            {\bfb XX XXXXX XXXX\par}
        }
        \blank[5cm]
        {\tfa
            \starttabulate[|l|p|]
            \NC XXXXXXXXX: \NC XXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXX \NC\NR
            \NC XXXXX: \NC XXXX XXX XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXX \NC\NR
            \stoptabulate
        }
    \stoptitlepagemakeup


    \completecontent
\stopfrontmatter

\startbodymatter
    \chapter{A Chapter}
    Some Text.
\stopbodymatter

\stoptext
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
\definemakeup
  [titlepage]
```

with

```
\definemakeup
  [titlepage]
  [headerstate=none]
```

This removes the header and the line below. For more options
see [ConTeXt Wiki -
setupmakeup](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupmakeup)

Comment: Is makeup deprecated in favor of overlays?

Comment: @DanielLyons No. It's two different mechanisms for two different things.